# How do I filter the rows that contains English characters in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I know Microsoft Excel is unable to use Regex. Also, the Filter function can only accept 2 custom filters, e.g. Contains "a" or Contains "b".

In an Excel file which contains English and non-English characters in cells, how can I filter rows if Row A contains any English characters (a-z, case insensitive)?

*p.s. I don't want to write Macro scripts (VB or .NET codes)*

Comment: Don't think excel can do this. I'd probably export to csv and load it into something else, eg. notepad++

Comment: Yes it can! Make a separate table with the same headers, write *a* under the relevant header, *b* under that, etc. until *z*. Now select your original table, choose Data/Advanced Filter, en use the new table as Criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the formula below. It assumes that the range is a single column.

```
=LET(data,
       BYROW(B2:B7,
         LAMBDA(row,
           IF(SUM(IFERROR(
              FIND({"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"},
                LOWER(row)),0)),row,""))),FILTER(data,data<>""))
```

**Explanation:** The formula first convert characters to lower cases. Then, try to find if characters from a to z are found in the row. If yes, the positions (where the characters are found within the text) are summed. We will have a number greater than 0. This is applied to each row in the range B2 to B7. Finally, the data is filtered to removed row that don't have them.

Change B2:B7 to match your range.

[image]

**Edit (based on the comment by OP)**: If you have to filter a table (B2 to F5) based on a column (B2 to B5), adapt the following formula:

```
=FILTER(B2:F5,B2:B5=
       BYROW(B2:B5,
         LAMBDA(row,
           IF(SUM(IFERROR(
              FIND({"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"},
                LOWER(row)),0)),row,""))))
```

[image]

Comment: That's amazing. I never use `LAMBDA()` and `LET()` functions before. If I want to check row B for the existence of English characters, and then filter the whole table which has columns B to F, how can I do it? i.e. for example if the cell B2, B3 and B5 contains English character, the table will show only row 2, 3 and 5 only. Thanks.

Comment: @Raptor See edit to my answer.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio A little shorter version: `=FILTER(A2:B10,BYROW(B2:B10,LAMBDA(rw,OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(CHAR(SEQUENCE(26,,97)),rw))))))` using `SEQUENCE` to generate the characters; `SEARCH` for a case-insensitive search, and `OR(ISNUMBER(...` to generate the `TRUE/FALSE` array for the filter.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Very very useful formula. Thanks. I knew it could be shortened but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for both marvellous answer.

Comment: One more comment on the formula, the result table will add a `0` if the original cell is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Up front, I am not an Excel expert. VBA and all these formulas may be too complex to filter data within a given column and with filled columns left and right.

My suggestion is to give ASAP a try (at least it is free for 90 days). I use it frequently and it has great support. No, I do not work for them.

ASAP does support regex.

In the attachment your post and some replies are mixed with dates in a column.
Then ASAP > Select > Regular Expression - [a-z]

Just a suggestion.

[ASAP using regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQh0L.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).